# Json Serialization accepts numeric input for boolean variable

Tags: java, json, spring, boolean

I am developing a REST API using spring MVC.
One of the service is used to fetch the train details with some request object .
Request object :

```
TrainRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6280494678832642677L;
    private String travelMonth;
    private boolean departOnly; 
}
```

I have used below request to test the service.

```
{ 
"travelMonth": "DEC2016",
"departOnly":0
}
```

I have seen that 0 is serialized and assigned to departOnly as false .Also I tested with other than 0 and got departOnly as true.
But I dont want to have numeric input for boolean variables.
Help me how to restrict in Spring validation or Java to have only true/false in defined boolean varaible.

Answer (score 0):

```
TrainRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6280494678832642677L;
    private String travelMonth;
    private int departOnlyInt;            // Serialized instead of departOnly
    private transient boolean departOnly;  // Not serialized

............................
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream o)  throws IOException {
    departOnlyInt = departOnly ? 1 : 0;  
    o.defaultWriteObject();  
  }

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream o) throws IOException,
          ClassNotFoundException {
    o.defaultReadObject();
    switch(departOnlyInt) {
         case 0: 
              departOnly = false; break; 

         case 1: 
              departOnly = true; break; 

         default: 
              throw new IOException ("Invalid boolean: " + departOnlyInt);  
    }
  }
..................
```

}